# Problem in the second-derivative symbol.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology

[image]

The second derivative of this symbol according to the rules that we have learned the correct mathematical, I wish to know why this symbol is not used.

Comment: You should interpret the symbol $dx$ as a "single quantity"...

Comment: The quantity $d^2 y / dx$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user The OP is showing work that leads up to the use of the notation: $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx}\cdot \dfrac 1{dx}=\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$.

Comment: ...and then you can simplify further by cancelling the $d\,$s, right?

Comment: In "The Road to Reality" Roger Penrose suggests that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ should instead be $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$ because that's what you get when you apply the quotient rule to $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ and hints that this would make things like $d^2x$ make sense as algebraic quantities on their own.

Comment: I have never liked this notation because I would like to interpret $\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ as the derivative of $x^2$. But in the second derivative notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, $dx^2$ means $(dx)^2$.

Comment: The rules I follow (made up) when dealing with $d$ are: (1) $d$ is a prefix operator on an expression, (2) the operator $d$ binds tighter than exponents so $dy^2$ is $(dy)^2$ (3) exponent on operator is a shorthand of repeating an operator $d dy$ = $d(dy)$ = $d^2 y$, (4) Use parens when needed $d(x^2)$ is not $dx^2 = (dx)^2$ and (5) $d$ is linear $d(a+b) = da+db$ (6) equations involving $d$ must make sense: size must be similar: d(normal) = small, d(small)=small^2, (d(normal))^2 = small^2, (normal) = (small)/(small) and units must match up: (length)/(time)^2 = acceleration

Answer (score 12):

The mnemonic is the following. The operator "d" is applied  twice to $y$, so $d(dy)=d^2y$. But to get the second derivative we have to divide by $dx$ twice namely the operator $d$ is applied once but the result is squared. So $dx\cdot dx=(dx)^2= dx^2$. This is not $d$ applied to $x^2$ ,  this is $(dx)^2$.

Comment: It is useful to note that one means $(dx)^2$ when one writes $dx^2$.

Answer (score 7):

$(dx)^2$ is not $d^2x^2$ because there is no quantity called $d$.  Rather $dx$ can be thought of as an infinitely small increment of the variable $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Really, the standard second derivative symbol $d^2\over dx^2$ should be considered an abuse of notation in its own right.  The first derivative symbol $d\over dx$ is already a "single symbol", so iterating it twice should yield $({d\over dx})^2$.  Without parentheses that yields ${d\over dx}^2$, which is confusingly like $d^2\over dx$, which is very very wrong ($d$ isn't really a separate thing you can square).  So, by convention, it is permitted to re-write it as $d^2\over dx^2$ --- but that's an abuse of notation.  Abuses of notation are only permitted when they are conventional or useful, and further simplify to $d^2\over d^2x^2$ is neither.

Answer (score 2):

Note what 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}[y]=g(x)
$$
where $y=y(x)$. So, it is convenient define

$$
\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{d}{dx}[y]\right]=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[y]=\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}
$$
to designate the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

we have per definition $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Please note tha $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator and not a quantity, so it makes sense to write
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \circ \frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} $$

which means applying the operator twice.